# Arduino +gsm module +httpread freezing

Tags: http, arduino, gsm, at-command

i am trying to make a interactive semaphore and for that i am using a rgb matrix connected to arduino mega and a web server with a database from witch i read colors. the database is controlled by a android application that is working fine, but i have problem with arduino code.

The arduino have to do the folowing:
1. connect to internet using a GSM module.
2. connect to a php on website and send an id, and receive with httpread the color from database
3. light the led matrix with the specific color and blink the matrix on a 500ms or less interval.

**PROBLEM: the code that i wrote is working until after some time is freezing and i do not why. in fact the matrix still blink  with last color lets say green even the color is changed to red in database**.

Please help me with this!
this is the code that i tryed:

```
//#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Adafruit_GFX.h>   // Core graphics library
#include <RGBmatrixPanel.h> // Hardware-specific library

#define CLK 11  // MUST be on PORTB! (Use pin 11 on Mega)
#define LAT 10
#define OE  9
#define A   A0
#define B   A1
#define C   A2

RGBmatrixPanel matrix(A, B, C, CLK, LAT, OE, false);
#define myGSM (Serial2) // RX, TX
enum _parseState {
  PS_DETECT_MSG_TYPE,
  PS_IGNORING_COMMAND_ECHO,
  PS_HTTPACTION_TYPE,
  PS_HTTPACTION_RESULT,
  PS_HTTPACTION_LENGTH,
  PS_HTTPREAD_LENGTH,
  PS_HTTPREAD_CONTENT
};

enum _actionState {
  AS_IDLE,
  AS_WAITING_FOR_RESPONSE
};
byte actionState = AS_IDLE;
unsigned long lastActionTime = 0;
byte parseState = PS_DETECT_MSG_TYPE;
char buffer[80];
byte pos = 0;
int contentLength = 0;
long timestamp = 0;
boolean ledstate = false;
int delayLength = 500; // setarea intervalului de citire baza de date
int ledPin = 13;
void resetBuffer() {
  memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));
  pos = 0;
}

String statusul = "";

void sendmyGSM(String msg, int waitMs = 100) {
  myGSM.println(msg);
  while (myGSM.available()) {
    parseATText(myGSM.read());
  }
  delay(waitMs);
}
String imeiul = "866029034128290";
void setup()
{
  myGSM.begin(115200);
  delay(1000);
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println("Setup begin");
  matrix.begin();
  delay(1000);
  matrix.fillScreen(0);
  matrix.setTextSize(1);     // size 1 == 8 pixels high
  matrix.setTextWrap(false); // Don't wrap at end of line - will do ourselves
  matrix.setCursor(5, 0);
  matrix.setTextColor(matrix.Color333(0, 7, 0));
  matrix.println("init");
  delay(10000);
  sendmyGSM("AT+CGATT=1");
  sendmyGSM("AT+SAPBR=3,1,APN,net");
  sendmyGSM("AT+SAPBR=1,1", 3000);
  sendmyGSM("AT+HTTPINIT");
  sendmyGSM("AT+HTTPPARA=\"CID\",1");
  sendmyGSM("AT+HTTPPARA=URL,http://sanctiuni.ddns.net/CNVC/Arduino.php?pan=" + imeiul);
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  unsigned long now = millis();
  if ( actionState == AS_IDLE ) {
    if ( now > lastActionTime + 1500 ) {
      sendmyGSM("AT+HTTPINIT", 100);
      sendmyGSM("AT+HTTPPARA=\"CID\",1", 100);
      sendmyGSM("AT+HTTPPARA=URL,http://sanctiuni.ddns.net/CNVC/Arduino.php?pan=" + imeiul, 100);
      sendmyGSM("AT+HTTPACTION=0");
      lastActionTime = now;
      actionState = AS_WAITING_FOR_RESPONSE;
    }
  }

  while (myGSM.available()) {
    lastActionTime = now;
    parseATText(myGSM.read());
  }

  if ( millis() - timestamp > delayLength ) {
    // half a s second has passed, do something
    ledstate = !ledstate; // toggles the ledState between true/false
    if (ledstate == true) {
      matrix.fillScreen(0);
      digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);

    }
    if (ledstate == false) {

      matrix.fillScreen(1);
      digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
    }
    timestamp = millis();
  }
}

void verifica_status() {
  if (statusul == "rosu") {
    Serial.println("Panou-rosul");
    //matrix.fillScreen(0);
    matrix.fillRect(0, 0, matrix.width(), matrix.height(), matrix.Color333(7, 0, 0));
    //matrix.fillScreen(matrix.Color333(7, 0, 0));
  }
  else if (statusul == "galben") {
    Serial.println("Panou-GALBENUL");
    //matrix.fillScreen(0);
    // matrix.fillScreen(matrix.Color333(7, 7, 0));
    matrix.fillRect(0, 0, matrix.width(), matrix.height(), matrix.Color333(7, 7, 0));
  }
  else if (statusul == "albastru") {
    Serial.println("Panou-albastrul");
    // matrix.fillScreen(0);
    //matrix.fillScreen(matrix.Color333(0, 0, 7));
    matrix.fillRect(0, 0, matrix.width(), matrix.height(), matrix.Color333(0, 0, 7));
  }

  else if (statusul == "verde") {
    Serial.println("Panou-verdele");
    matrix.fillScreen(0);
    matrix.setTextSize(1);     // size 1 == 8 pixels high
    matrix.setTextWrap(false); // Don't wrap at end of line - will do ourselves
    matrix.setCursor(8, 0);
    matrix.setTextColor(matrix.Color333(0, 7, 0));
    matrix.println("OK");
  }
}

void parseATText(byte b) {

  buffer[pos++] = b;

  if ( pos >= sizeof(buffer) )
    resetBuffer(); // just to be safe

  switch (parseState) {
    case PS_DETECT_MSG_TYPE:
      {
        if ( b == '\n' )
          resetBuffer();
        else {
          if ( pos == 3 && strcmp(buffer, "AT+") == 0 ) {
            parseState = PS_IGNORING_COMMAND_ECHO;
          }
          else if ( b == ':' ) {
            if ( strcmp(buffer, "+HTTPACTION:") == 0 ) {
              //Serial.println("Received HTTPACTION");
              parseState = PS_HTTPACTION_TYPE;
            }
            else if ( strcmp(buffer, "+HTTPREAD:") == 0 ) {
              //Serial.println("Received HTTPREAD");
              parseState = PS_HTTPREAD_LENGTH;
            }
            resetBuffer();
          }
        }
      }
      break;

    case PS_IGNORING_COMMAND_ECHO:    {
        if ( b == '\n' ) {
          //Serial.print("Ignoring echo: ");
          //Serial.println(buffer);
          parseState = PS_DETECT_MSG_TYPE;
          resetBuffer();
        }
      }
      break;

    case PS_HTTPACTION_TYPE:    {
        if ( b == ',' ) {
          //Serial.print("HTTPACTION type is ");
          //Serial.println(buffer);
          parseState = PS_HTTPACTION_RESULT;
          resetBuffer();
        }
      }
      break;

    case PS_HTTPACTION_RESULT:    {
        if ( b == ',' ) {
          //Serial.print("HTTPACTION result is ");
          //Serial.println(buffer);
          parseState = PS_HTTPACTION_LENGTH;
          resetBuffer();
        }
      }
      break;

    case PS_HTTPACTION_LENGTH: {
        if ( b == '\n' ) {
          //Serial.print("HTTPACTION length is ");
          //Serial.println(buffer);
          // now request content
          myGSM.print("AT+HTTPREAD=0,");
          myGSM.println(buffer);
          parseState = PS_DETECT_MSG_TYPE;
          resetBuffer();
        }
      }
      break;

    case PS_HTTPREAD_LENGTH:    {
        if ( b == '\n' ) {
          contentLength = atoi(buffer);
          parseState = PS_HTTPREAD_CONTENT;
          resetBuffer();
        }
      }
      break;

    case PS_HTTPREAD_CONTENT: {
        //Serial.write(b);
        contentLength--;
        if ( contentLength <= 0 ) {
          String str(buffer);
          str.trim();
          statusul = str;
          verifica_status();
          parseState = PS_DETECT_MSG_TYPE;
          resetBuffer();
          //Serial.print("\n\n\n");
          actionState = AS_IDLE;

        }
      }
      break;
  }
}
```